# Duplicated Product Title and Short description

Tags: product

I have a small problem with one shop. By the product page 2 times appear the Title and short description for Product. I can not find from where come this problem
[image]

```
    <?php
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $helperThis = $this->helper('ultimo/template_catalog_product_view');
    $helperSnippets = $this->helper('ultimo/rsnippets');

    //CSS classes based on product type
    $productTypeId = $_product->getTypeId();
    $productTypeClasses = '';
    if ($productTypeId === 'grouped') {
        $productTypeClasses .= ' is-type-grouped';
    }

    //
    $shortDescription = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');

    //Rich snippets
    $useRichSnippets = ($helperSnippets->isEnabledOnProductPage() && $productTypeId !== 'grouped');
    $priceProperties = '';
    if ($useRichSnippets)
    {
        $priceProperties = $helperSnippets->getPriceProperties($_product); //Has to be called before getOfferItemscope
    }

    //Get grid classes for product page sections
    $grid = $helperThis->getGridClasses();

    //Product collaterals
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    $section = array();
    $relatedProductsHtml = '';
    $upsellProductsHtml = '';

    //Related products.
    //If related products not assigned to collateral data container.
    if (!$theme->getCfg('product_page/collateral_related'))
    {
        $replaceRelated = $theme->getCfg('product_page/replace_related');
        if ($replaceRelated == 1) //don't replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('related_products_wrapper')))
                $relatedProductsHtml = $tmpHtml;
            //$relatedProductsHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('related_products_wrapper'));
        }
        elseif ($replaceRelated == 2) //if related is empty, replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('related_products_wrapper')))
                $relatedProductsHtml = $tmpHtml;
            else //related empty
                if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_product_replace_related'))
                    $relatedProductsHtml = '<div class="block_product_replace_related">'. $tmpHtml .'</div>';
        }
        elseif ($replaceRelated == 3) //replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_product_replace_related'))
                $relatedProductsHtml = '<div class="block_product_replace_related">'. $tmpHtml .'</div>';
        }
    }

    //Up-sell products.
    //If up-sell products not assigned to collateral data container.
    if (!$theme->getCfg('product_page/collateral_upsell'))
    {
        $replaceUpsell = $theme->getCfg('product_page/replace_upsell');
        if ($replaceUpsell == 1) //don't replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products_wrapper')))
                $upsellProductsHtml = $tmpHtml;
            //$upsellProductsHtml = $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products_wrapper');
        }
        elseif ($replaceUpsell == 2) //if upsell is empty, replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = trim($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products_wrapper')))
                $upsellProductsHtml = $tmpHtml;
            else //upsell empty
                if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_product_replace_upsell'))
                    $upsellProductsHtml = '<div class="block_product_replace_upsell">'. $tmpHtml .'</div>';
        }
        elseif ($replaceUpsell == 3) //replace with static block
        {
            if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_product_replace_upsell'))
                $upsellProductsHtml = '<div class="block_product_replace_upsell">'. $tmpHtml .'</div>';
        }
    }

    //Assign blocks to selected position
    $p = array();

    //Related products
    $position = $theme->getCfg('product_page/related_position');
    if (isset($p[$position]))
        $p[$position] = $p[$position] . $relatedProductsHtml;
    else
        $p[$position] = $relatedProductsHtml;

    //Up-sell products
    $position = $theme->getCfg('product_page/upsell_position');
    if (isset($p[$position]))
        $p[$position] = $p[$position] . $upsellProductsHtml;
    else
        $p[$position] = $upsellProductsHtml;

    //Product collateral data (displayed as tabs or stacked blocks)
    $position = $theme->getCfg('product_page/collateral_position');
    if (isset($p[$position]))
        $p[$position] = $p[$position] . $this->getChildHtml('productCollaterals');
    else
        $p[$position] = $this->getChildHtml('productCollaterals');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view nested-container" <?php if ($useRichSnippets) echo $helperSnippets->getProductItemscope(); ?>>

    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-column <?php echo $grid['imgCol']; ?>">

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('ultimo/labels')->getLabels($_product); //Product labels ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('container_product_image_1'); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="product-primary-column product-shop <?php echo $grid['primCol']; ?>">

            <div class="product-name">
                <h1 itemprop="name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true); //reviews ?>

            <?php if ($shortDescription): ?>
                <div class="short-description"><div class="std" itemprop="description"><?php echo $shortDescription; ?></div></div>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('container_product_primary_1'); ?>

            <?php if (isset($p['primCol_1'])) echo $p['primCol_1']; ?>

            <?php if ($sku = $_product->getSku()): ?>
                <?php if ($theme->getCfg('product_page/sku')): ?>
                    <div class="sku">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>: </span>
                        <span class="value"><?php echo $sku; ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($useRichSnippets): ?><meta itemprop="productID" content="sku:<?php echo $sku; ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls'); //alerts ?>

            <?php if ($extrahint_html = $this->getChildHtml('extrahint')): //qty increments ?>
                <div class="extrahint-wrapper"><?php echo $extrahint_html; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div <?php if ($useRichSnippets) echo $helperSnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>
                <div class="product-type-data<?php echo $productTypeClasses; ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?></div>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
                <?php echo $priceProperties; ?>
            </div> <?php //end: offers ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): //add to cart when no options (e.g. simple products) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
                <?php if ($container1_html = $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true)): ?>
                    <div class="container1-wrapper"><?php echo $container1_html; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($addtoLinksHtml = $this->getChildHtml('addto')): //compare, wishlist, send to friend ?>
                <div class="action-box clearer">
                    <?php echo $addtoLinksHtml; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (isset($p['primCol_2'])) echo $p['primCol_2']; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('container_product_primary_2'); ?>

        </div> <!-- end: product-shop -->

        <?php if (isset($grid['secCol'])): //(!empty($secondaryColUnits)): ?>

            <div class="product-secondary-column <?php echo $grid['secCol']; ?> custom-sidebar-right">
                <div class="inner">

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('container_product_secondary_1'); ?>

                    <?php if (isset($p['secCol_1'])) echo $p['secCol_1']; ?>

                    <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('product_secondary_top_placeholder')): //Brand logo ?>
                        <div class="feature-wrapper bottom-border"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if (isset($p['secCol_2'])) echo $p['secCol_2']; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('container_product_secondary_2'); ?>

                    <?php if (isset($p['secCol_3'])) echo $p['secCol_3']; ?>

                </div>
            </div> <!-- end: product-secondary-column -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
            <?php if ($container2_html = $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true)): ?>
                <div class="box-additional <?php echo $grid['cont2Col']; ?>">
                    <div class="container2-wrapper"><?php echo $container2_html; ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>

    <?php //Lower primary column ?>
    <div class="box-additional <?php echo $grid['lowerPrimCol']; ?>">

        <?php if (isset($p['lowerPrimCol_1'])) echo $p['lowerPrimCol_1']; ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews'); //Reviews ?>

    </div> <!-- end: box-tabs -->

    <?php //Lower secondary column ?>
    <?php if (isset($p['lowerSecCol_2'])): ?>
        <div class="box-additional box-sidebar custom-sidebar-right <?php echo $grid['lowerSecCol']; ?>">
            <div class="inner"><?php echo $p['lowerSecCol_2']; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (isset($p['lowerPrimCol_2'])): ?>
        <div class="box-additional <?php echo $grid['lowerPrimCol']; ?>"><?php echo $p['lowerPrimCol_2']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- end: product-view -->
```

[image]

Comment: You can find product `Title` and `Description` code under **`magento/app/design/frontend/THEME_PACKAGE/THEME_FOLDER/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`** file

Comment: I find this one but the problem is that there is no duplicates and I can not understand from where come this

Comment: Add you `.phtml` code in question.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Is your website hosted on production server? If so can you please share website URL. B'cus your code seems okay and its worked on my local system.

Comment: what mean production server?

Comment: I mean is your website `live` or you worked on `local` server?

Comment: I work am local server

Comment: For further debugging you need to enable `Template Path` and `Block Name`  hint, see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enabling `Template Path` and `Block Name` hints for further troubleshooting. To enable this option follow below steps:

**Steps to get Template Path Hints:**

> 1. Login to Magento Admin panel
> 2. Go to **System->Configuration**.
> 3. The Template Path and Block name will only appear for current website. So change the **Current Configuration Scope** to '**Main
>      Website**'.
> 4. Go to the **Advanced** section and click on Developers.
> 5. Expand the **Debug** tab.
> 6. Set the **Template Path Hints** to '**Yes**'.
> 7. Click on '**Save Configuration**' button.
> 8. Open Magento user panel and see the template path hints. It shows each file where the page element is located in.

[image]

---

**Steps to get Block Name Hints:**

> 1. Login to Magento Admin panel
> 2. Go to **System->Configuration**.
> 3. The Template Path and Block name will only appear for current website. So change the **Current Configuration Scope** to '**Main
>      Website**.
> 4. Go to the **Advanced** section and click on **Developers**.
> 5. Expand the **Debug** tab.
> 6. Set the **Block Name Hints** to '**Yes**.
> 7. Click on **Save Configuration** button.
> 8. Open Magento user panel and see the Block name hints.

[image]

After enabling this you will get from where this duplicate information has been rendered.

Source of above content: http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/

Comment: Thank you for your help but this tip don help me, I can not find from where come this. Look at the image from the post

Comment: Its seems your **`frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`** file is render two times.

Comment: Change your frontend theme with any other rather than current one, and observe the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Here, you call catalog/product/view.phtml twice.

See the below screen cast : http://prntscr.com/aoeu6r

i think it may be .xml problem

Comment: and in witch XML file can I check? Witch file responds for the Item page?

Comment: you must be use ultimo theme,
here, yo have to check catalog.xml or local.xml file
{{frontend/ultimo/default/layout}}